# Print string inside frame

Tags: c, string

I need to print centered string inside a frame of square stars pattern.

EXAMPLE:

const char tekst[]="This is example of string programming in C";
int width = 20;
OUTPUT:

```
********************
* This is example  * 
* of string progr- *
*   amming in C    *
********************
```

If number of spaces that need to be added is odd, excess space should be added to the right.
If the whole word cannot fit in the row, dash is added and word continues in the next row.
Auxiliary strings are not allowed.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void framed(const char *tekst, int width) {
  int i, j = 0, count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    printf("*");
  printf("\n");
  while (tekst[j] != '\0') {
    count++;
    if (count == 1)
      printf("* ");
    printf("%c", tekst[j]);
    j++;
    if (count + 5 > width) {
      printf(" *");
      printf("\n");
      count = 0;
    }
    if (j == strlen(tekst))
      for (i = 0; i < width - count; i++)
        printf(" ");
  }
  printf("*\n");
  for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    printf("*");
}
int main() {
  const char tekst[] = "This is example of string programming in C";
  int width = 20;
  framed(tekst, width);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
********************
* This is example  *
* of string progra *
* mming in C          *
********************
```

Could you help me to fix my code for correct output?

Comment: Please do not change a question so that an existing answer gets invalidated.

Comment: Where is the logic for hyphenation?

Comment: I changed my code and question a little, sorry for that, I need something different

Comment: @Yunnosch please edit your answer or remove it

Comment: I answered the question as it was asked. You changed the question. If you have a new question please create a new question post for the different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you take the additional character `"* "" *"` into account (with a little off-by-one because of `>`):

```
if (count + 5 > width)
```

Here you don't:

```
for (i = 0; i < width - count; i++)
```

If you do take them into account, it (the frame) works.

```
for (i = 0; i <= width - (count +5); i++)
```

assuming that you also output consistently a little later

```
printf(" *\n");
```

I recommend to replace the very magic number 5 with the less magic number of additional characters; 4 for `"*  *"` and to adapt the conditions `<=` and `>`.

The other differences to required output (centering instead of left aligning and inserting the "-" correctly have not even been attempted by the shown code, so I assume that they are not part of what is asked about.

Comment: could you post whole code please?

Comment: I do not think that you would benefit from that. The code shows that you need exercise with making loop conditions.

Comment: As a hint, to properly deal with centering the text, you will need to know how many words (and/or partial words) are going to fit in the line before you just start printing willy nilly. You will need to save a pointer to where in the text your last line left off, then calculate how many extra spaces are needed to center it befor printing.